# Wordpress docker uninstalls plugins every startup

Tags: wordpress, docker

I'm running wordpress in a docker container using this command (with redacted info)

```
docker run -itd --name wordpress -v /opt/Wordpress:/opt/Wordpress -e WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=....amazonaws.com -e WORDPRESS_DB_USER=username -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=password-p 8080:80 wordpress:latest
```

But every time it stops running and starts up again all the plugins I've installed are gone, the raw content stays but no plugins.

Is there a way I can install a plugin in that run command? Or a way to preserve them from being deleted? I have the .zip of all the plugins

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Docker expert, but it sounds like this is something that could be solved by mounting a local directory to the container. This directory will be preserved and won't be overwritten whenever the image is built again or the container is restarted.

You can do this using a variation of this argument: `v "/your/dir:/var/html/your/dir".

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#mount-tmpfs---tmpfs

Also, it might be worth wrapping all of this up into a `docker-compose.yml` file. It's just a bit easier to maintain and see what's going on when Docker is run.

Finally, for plugin management specifically, I'd recommend using Composer to manage these dependencies. Using the Composer Installers package, you can `composer install` to drop plugins right into your plugins directory. See an example of this setup on Docker here:

https://github.com/alexmacarthur/wp-skateboard